# Setting Priority for wifi configuration in android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I have to set a priority for wifi configuration sothat I have to always connect to specified wifi network  so that device ignores other available wifi in the region.

```
  configuration.priority = 100000;
```

It is connecting to the last known connected wifi network and ignoring specified wifi network.

Comment: I have followed https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/CH-ns_S8S5A link which could not help. Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to set priority for a particular Wifi Configuration, you must use

```
config.priority = value;

WifiManager.updateNetwork(config);
```

and you should use the below api after updating

```
WifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

I was able to set priority for my configured network.

**Note**:

- By default the android system will provide highest priority for the last known connected wifi network. If you want to set a higher priority for any other configuration, set the value with respect to the highest value set by the android system rather going for some numerical digit.
- Default priority value is in relative with the highest value and its also based on its usage preference. User set value will be changed if the network is manually selected.

Comment: The documentation says that `WifiConfiguration.priority` was removed in API 26. Does it still work ? If not, what is the alternative method to set a wifi configuration priority ?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, changes to pre-configured networks should be saved to make an effect.

> addOrUpdateNetworkNative(WifiConfiguration config);

Comment: Oleksandr Kravchuk I understand by using the method, it will change the priority but for specified instance, I require specified network to be autoconnected irrespective of other network availability

Comment: I tried using reflection by invoking the required method but unable to get object from wificonfigstore. Any suggestions on this please

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably a bit late, but I've been looking at the same thing, and apparently 99 999 is the highest value you can set, anything higher than that gets ignored [From here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/CH-ns_S8S5A)